# Auto Submitted form not carrying the values into Page which is mentioned in Action attribute of <form> tag

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to do auto form submission.It works fine and it redirected to the action page.But,it does not carry the values.Please help me to find the solution.

```
<form method="POST" action="SamplePage" name="myForm" id="formone">
    <input type="hidden" name="AMT" value="10"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="ID" id="cust"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="bu" name="i"/>
</form>
```

I used `document.getElementById("formone").submit();` the for auto submission.

Comment: could you show the whole code? So the form etc.

Comment: How about the HTML code for the actual form (minimal example), plus the browser you're using?

Comment: Have you add in html 'name' tags in all of your inputs?

Comment: yes i have added 'name' for all my inputs

Comment: <form method="POST" action="SamplePage" name="myForm" id="formone"><br>

<input type="hidden" name="AMT" value="10"/><br>
<input type="hidden" name="ID" id="cust"/><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="bu" name="i"/><br>
</form>

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
document.forms["formone"].submit();
```

or you can try like

```
document.formone.submit();
```

Where your form name should be **formone**

And at your action page try to access the REQUEST values

```
print_r($_REQUEST);
```

Comment: The form is being submitted so the code to do that doesn't appear to be the issue. This really seems like a non-answer.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question.But above code does not work